# Hide all DIVs that don't contain all specified classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my page I have a large number of DIVs, each DIV represents a specific product, with a series of characteristics. I'm using those characteristics as classes, so every product would start similarly to this:

```
<div class='classA classB classC classD classE classF'>
  Product Card
</div>
```

Ideally on my page I'd like to have one `<select>` element for each class, so that when the user select a value from the dropdown, only the `<div>` with the corresponding class remains displayed on the page, while all the others are hidden.

Also, the check on the class has to consider ALL the classes at the same time. By this I mean that if a user selects value from 3 dropdowns, only the `<div>` that have ALL the 3 classes selected will be shown.

I've tried to implement this idea using javascript, with the following code:

```js
function filterPowerInput() {
  var powerInput = document.getElementById("powerInput").value;
  if (powerInput == 1) {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ph3ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClasses.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var myClassesTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.ph1ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClassesTwo.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClassesTwo[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else if (powerInput == 3) {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ph1ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClasses.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClasses[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var myClassesTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.ph3ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClassesTwo.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClassesTwo[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  } else {
    var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.ph1ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClasses.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClasses[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    var myClassesTwo = document.querySelectorAll('.ph3ph'),
      i = 0,
      l = myClassesTwo.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClassesTwo[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

This example works fine for a class that can only assume 2 values, but it becomes impossible to manage as soon as a class has many more value (they could go up to 12). Also, by using similar version of the code above on different dropdowns, they will override each other, I haven't found a way yet to make them work together as I need.

I hope it's clear enough, otherwise just ask. Thanks a lot for your time as always!

(The rest of my page is a mix of PHP/HTML/Javascript)

Comment: The php might be irrelevant, but it would be helpful to see your "*[mcve]*" html in order to provide specific help to you, and practical help to future visitors who come across this question in order to solve their own, similar, problems.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you - also there are no jQuery in your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you meant

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sel").on("change",function() {
    var classLst = ["selDiv"];
    $(".sel").each(function() {
      var val = this.value;
      if (val) classLst.push("class"+val);
    });
    classLst.sort();
    $(".selDiv").each(function() {
      var divClassLst = $(this).attr("class");
      if (divClassLst) {
        $(this).toggle(divClassLst.split(" ").sort().join(".") == classLst.join("."));
      }  
    }) 
  }).change(); // run when loaded
});
```

```css
.selDiv { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Note: Possible combinations: </b><i>A,B,C; D,E</i> and <i>C,D</i>
<hr/>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="A" selected>A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B" selected>B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C" selected>C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<select class="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<div class='selDiv classA classB classC'>
  Product Card A B C
</div>
<div class='selDiv classD classE'>
  Product Card D E 
</div>
<div class='selDiv classC classD'>
  Product Card C D
</div>
```

Comment: How would I do the reverse? Starting will ALL divs visible and hide the one where the class does't match the selected one? I was trying to play around with your function but can't make it work the opposite way...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was changing the wrong line. Final thing: I'd like for div to show up only if they have ALL the classes selected. So if I select something in classA and classB I only want to see results that have both classes. This is not happening at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the continued support; however after these changes the entire code doesn't seems to be working. Even trying to run your code as it is on this page doesn't produce any result. DIVs stay hidden no matter what is selected.

Comment: Try A,B,C ONLY on dropdown 1 2 and 3 - I updated to select the first div using A,B,C

Answer (score 1):

Something far more important than answer to your question. I know it's not an answer but I had to show the importance of this matter.

As a developer if you write a block of the same code more than once - something is not right. Why not simply writing a function that does the same procedure?

```
var customtog = function(cls, dis){
  var myClasses = document.querySelectorAll(cls),
      i = 0,
      l = myClasses.length;

  for (i; i < l; i++) {
      myClasses[i].style.display = dis;
  }
}
```

**So look how your code is gonna look now:**
Far more easier to follow and maintain.

```
if(powerInput == 1)
{
  customtog('.ph3ph', 'none');
  customtog('.ph1ph', 'block');
}
else if(powerInput == 3)
{
  customtog('.ph1ph', 'none');
  customtog('.ph3ph', 'block');       
}
else
{
  customtog('.ph1ph', 'block');
  customtog('.ph3ph', 'block');
}
```

**Update - Following @mplungjan comment**

```
customtog('.ph3ph', powerInput==1?'none':'block');
customtog('.ph1ph', powerInput==1?'block':'none');
```

Comment: `customtog('.ph3ph', powerInput==1?'none':'block');
 customtog('.ph1ph', powerInput==1?'block':'none');`

Comment: Damm... simplicity in its finest.

Comment: You may need to make it even simpler and allow the 3rd option too

Comment: I know the code posted originally is a bit of a mess but I'm still at the very beginning of the development and it was helpful to visualise all the steps! Thanks for the suggestions on how to simply it, still this won't make a difference in terms of concatenating multiple effects together.

Comment: Hi Ofir. We try to discourage offering voting advice here - it is mostly added by people posting poor quality questions and attempting to dodge well-deserved DVs. If you would rather not have credit for your answer, post as Community Wiki (you can do that in an edit now if you wish).